# MYSQL: Select most recent row with 2 or more columns distinct

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with a system that stores students' responses to questions in a table by creating a new entry each time the student resubmits his/her answer. I only want the final answer though. I have looked at some of the greatest-n-per-group posts on here and have attempted to apply some of those queries, but they haven't yielded the results I was hoping for yet. The closest that I have gotten was getting the most recent answer to the most recent question, but I need answers to every question that the student has responded to. Below is the closest that I have gotten so far.

```
select t1.* from response_history as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN response_history as t2
    ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
        AND (t1.`date` > t2.`date`
            OR (t1.`date` = t2.`date` AND t1.id > t2.id))
where t2.student_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just like most of the answers in [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1), you just have to group by and join on both the student ID and question ID.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM response_history AS t1
JOIN (SELECT student_id, session_question_id, MAX(date) AS date
      FROM response_history
      GROUP BY student_id, session_question_id) AS t2
ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id 
    AND t1.session_question_id = t2.session_question_id
    AND t1.date = t2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error and taking a peek at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612268/2910057) answer, I was able to come up with this query that seems to work correctly.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM response_history t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.student_id, t2.session_question_id, MAX(`date`) as `date`
        FROM response_history t2
        group by session_question_id, student_id) as groupedt2
ON t1.student_id = groupedt2.student_id and t1.`date` = groupedt2.`date`
```

Comment: You also need `t1.session_question_id = groupedt2.session_question_id`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I've selected your answer as correct.